# Create a Views that displays all unused taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I found this article about how to create a Views to display all active taxonomy terms: https://www.drupal.org/node/770782

I want to achieve the exact contrary: Get a list of all terms that are not used by my nodes.

Can I reach this with Views UI, relashionships, etc?

Any clue is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by View **relationships and aggregation**

1) Add a new view of view type "term"

2) Add Field Taxonomy: Term Name

3) Add Relationship "Taxonomy term: Content with term"

4) In the View : Advanced section , Enable Aggregation

5) Add new Filter **nid**, `Aggregation type` = **Count DISTINCT** , Select `Relationship` = **node** , `Operator`= **equal to** , `Value`= **0**

Comment: Many thanks. It works like a charm. I still have some trouble with Views UI understanding, in particular with relashionships and contextual filters. You helped a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to trust on the proposed solution, if you have unpublished nodes, because [unpublished entities do not appear in views](https://www.drupal.org/node/1182924)

If you use the aggregation view to delete orphaned taxonomy terms, you might loose information of your unpublished nodes. Consider using the "[delete orphaned terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/delete_orphaned_terms)" module